# Can't figure out how to code my css

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc-2

I'm a new poster in stackoverflow. The community seems really nice so I'll go ahead and post my question.

I'm trying to style a asp.net MVC2 form so that instead of having all the fields on a strait line, I would like to have it like so:

Label:   Text field
Label:   Text field

I know you could do that with a table but I would like to use CSS to accomplish that. I know a little bit about css but not enough to figure out what to do. The only thing I came close to was to but my fields as a unorder list then styling the li item.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Give the labels a class & add float:left to it.

There are plenty of [CSS](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/prettyaccessibleforms) [forms](http://articles.sitepoint.com/article/fancy-form-design-css) [tutorials](http://www.onextrapixel.com/2009/12/04/css-form-tutorial-how-to-improve-web-order-form-design/) around if you get [stuck](http://www.google.com.au/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=css+forms+tutorial&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&redir_esc=&ei=itgSTI6bKcaecemN6bwM).

Comment: And add a clear:left to your label style, this will ensure a new line for each. You might wish to set your labels and input elements to display:block or display:inline-block, too.

Comment: So, this is all suggesting changing the elements to block, then floating the labels left, then clearing them left to put them on a new line? That seems to me like the most roundabout way of accomplishing this. All these elements are already inline by default. Is this just the way to do it if you don't want any additional markup?

Answer (score 1):

There are likely dozens of ways to do it. If you're just trying to get a line break between your field / value pairs, wrap each line's worth of code in a `<div>` tag. Divs are block elements, meaning that by default there's a line break before and after them. Labels by default are inline, so you don't need to do anything special to get them to line up next to the text fields.

```
<div>
    <label>Label:</label><input type=text />
</div>
<div>
    <label>Label:</label><input type=text />
</div>
```